# How to re-dissect the selected packet in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing dissector for wireshark. There are some packets which can not be dissected because no context is in that packet. The context contains the information about which type of the packet's SDU is. So, I want to register a menu in wireshark and the user can select the type of SDU.

But there is a problem that after user select the type of SDU they must select other packet firstly and then re-select the packet so that the dissector will be called again.

My question is that is there a way to re-dissect the selected packet manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, I want to register a menu in wireshark and the user can select the type of SDU.

If you make it a preference for your dissector's protocol, you will not have to modify the Wireshark source to change the menus, and, when the preference is changed, all packets will be redissected automatically.  That's how we expect manually-configured items such as that to be handled in dissectors.

Answer (score 1):

You said "is there a way to re-dissect selected packet manually?"  If you really mean *manually*, then yes the user can manually do it - they can click the reload icon button on the toolbar.

If you mean *automatically* instead, by having your code do it for the user, then yes - if you're writing this dissector in C code: you can call `redissect_packets()`, usually followed by `redissect_all_packet_windows()` to cover the case of multiple packet details windows being open.

Comment: Note that if you will be building TShark or the Qt version of Wireshark, your dissector will not work in TShark or the Qt version of Wireshark, and might not even compile, if you call `redissect_packets()` from the dissector, as that function is only present in the GTK+ version of Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks, I use reload function call instead.